# c# GUI & DB for EV telemetry system

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, linq

This question relates to handling asynchronous data and displaying on a C# GUI. What is the best way to go about this.

I'm building an intelligent EV platform consisting of a bunch of hardware modules which communicate with each other via CAN bus. There are sensors for speed, battery data, GPS, 3axis accelerometer, 3axis gyro, temperature, humidity, solar power and a couple others. These are also relayed wirelessly to a notebook PC for remote display and logging. The design makes this communication layer generic, however in my implementation I am using UHF serial radios and packaging data with the MAVLINK protocol.

I'm using the Mavlink.net project (https://github.com/dsuarezv/mavlink.net) to generate a .dll that can decode my messages. I've also setup a basic WPF c# app that displays some of this data on screen. I also have a small portable class library I've written that sets up the mavlink .dll to receive data over the serial port and then does a switch case on the message ID which in turn calls a specific event handler based on the message ID. 
In my WPF application, I hook methods into the event handlers I'm interested in for data to display. Then in my methods I simply update my GUI labels with the data. For example:

```
evApi.GPSPosReceived += S_GPSPosReceived;
```

and then

```
private void S_GPSPosReceived(object sender, APIContainer<GPSPos> e)
    {
        //save MsgID to MessagesTable  and get generated ID
        //e.OriginalMessage.id

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
        {
            tbLat.Text = e.Obj.Lat.ToString();
            tbLon.Text = e.Obj.Lon.ToString();
            tbTimeUsec.Text = e.Obj.TimeUsec.ToString();
            tbFix.Text = e.Obj.FixType.ToString();
        }));
    }
```

I'm of average c# experience and skill. (electronic engineer, spend most of my time writing embedded c). I'm a bit stuck on how best to continue from here.. These are some of my issues:

I tried WPF as it seems to be the new way to do things. My experience however is with WinForms and I think it will be easier to setup graphs with zedgraph for example. Problem however is how to handle the cross thread calls without a thousand different delegates for each control on the form. Is there a better way for me to display this data than event handlers? Should I go with WPF or WinForms? Any example projects? (I've looked at a bunch but no huge success)

I also need to log data to a database. I've been advised to use sqlite and also use linq to make things very easy and dynamic. This is attractive because the DB can be built into the application without complicating the install on clients PCs. I also need to recall data and plot graphs or export as a CSV etc.. Any suggestions / help?

If you know of any similar projects, please do send me in the right direction! I want to make good design choices now before heading down a road that makes my life more difficult!

Comment: Forget winforms. Check Dynamic Data Display for WPF. Also, use MVVM and DataBinding, which is much better than the winforms approach.

Comment: you can also try something like this `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
{
 evApi.GPSPosReceived += S_GPSPosReceived;
}));`

Comment: Thanks @HighCore , any links / resources you can recommend to get me jump started with MVVM and Databinding related to my application?

Comment: Be very careful in how you implement this.  What manufacturers call "telemetry", ordinary people call "spying", and we tend to not like it...

Comment: @MasonWheeler , Thanks I will keep that in mind. I'm referring more from an electronics hardware point of view, where the electronics of the vehicle transmit 'telemetry' data and the desktop GUI receives this data for display and storage.